# Get list of xml from parent xml in sql

Tags: sql, xml

Need to get the list of xml present inside an xml. This is what I have tried.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = '<a><b /><c><d /><d /><d /></c></a>';

DECLARE @i_xml xml = @xml.value('(/a/b/c)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
Select @i_xml
```

But this gives me NULL

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Is it SQL Server?

Comment: yes it is SQL server

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample xml, `c` and `b` are on same child record of `<a>`. `value()` will give a scalar result, use `query()` instead.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = '<a><b /><c><d /><d /><d /></c></a>';

DECLARE @i_xml xml = @xml.query('(//a/c/child::*)') 
SELECT @i_xml
```

Comment: is there no way possible to use value only and get the inner xml as a string?

Comment: value() will yield to node value, not inner xml.

Comment: so you mean node value b, `@xml.value('(/a/b)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')` even this does not work, I am unable to get the node value as well gives me NULL

Comment: yes, because your data type is xml, value() will only get the scalar value, not xml.